# A method which, given a string, returns a string in which each character is separated by an asterisk

Tags: c#, strings

Use recursion in the solution.

I would really appreciate if you can help me to find a better way to do it.

```
public class AppendCharacterAfterEachCharacterInString
{
    int index =0;
    StringBuilder outputString = new StringBuilder();

    public string AppendInputCharacterAfterEachCharacterInString(string sInputString, string inputRepeatCharacter)
    {            
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sInputString))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Empty string !");
        }
        else
        {
            BuildNewString(sInputString, inputRepeatCharacter);
        }

        return outputString.ToString();
    }

    private void BuildNewString(string inputString, string repeatCharacter)
    {
        if (index < inputString.Length)
        { 
            outputString.Append(inputString[index]);

            if(!(inputString[index].ToString().Trim() == string.Empty) && !(index + 1 == inputString.Length))
              outputString.Append(repeatCharacter);                  

            index++;
            BuildNewString(inputString, repeatCharacter);  
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 10):

Well, you've *used* recursion, but I wouldn't say that's a recursive solution because you have variables outside your functions that control what your functions do.

A recursive solution will have a function that is repeatedly called with smaller and smaller sub-problems, terminating in a base case, that together will accomplish your goal. A key aspect of recursive solutions is that the recursive function *returns* a value - your method is `void` and so returns no value.

As a first step, discard your `index` variable entirely. At each recursive step, call `BuildNewString` with a smaller version of the same problem. Combine the results in such a way as to produce the desired result.

Comment: Nice try though :)

Answer (score 2):

IMO recursion isn't best the way to solve this problem, you can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688019/recursion-versus-iteration).

Before all, let's just hack it for fun :

```
public string InsertStringAfterEachCharacter(string input, string repeat)
{
     return String.Join(repeat, input.Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)));
}
```

---

Before we get to the recursive solution, let's look through your solution first since we are in code review~

```
int index =0;
StringBuilder outputString = new StringBuilder();
```

- Recursive function should not depend on external variables, unless it
  is configuration setting. 
   Another problem is that these
  variables doesn't get reinitialized when you call
  `AppendInputCharacterAfterEachCharacterInString(...)` again

```
//!(inputString[index].ToString().Trim() == string.Empty)
!char.IsWhiteSpace(inputString[index])
```

- In order to check if a character is a white space, you can use `char.IsWhiteSpace`. It is much shorter and self-explanatory.

---

```
public class StringHelper
{
    public static string InsertInBetween(string input, string separator)
    {
        return InsertInBetweenImpl(input, separator, 0);
    }
    private static string InsertInBetweenImpl(string input, string separator, int index)
    {
        var c = input[index];

        if (index == input.Length - 1)
            return char.IsWhiteSpace(c) ? string.Empty : c.ToString();

        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
            return InsertInBetweenImpl(input, separator, index + 1);

        var temp = InsertInBetweenImpl(input, separator, index + 1);
        return c + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(temp) ? String.Empty : separator + temp);
    }
}
```